# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Error

Tags: java, arrays

So I have an array Canvas[256][256] that has a random index Canvas[r][r] (r being random) set to 1. I then want to loop through the array to see exactly which index is not 0, and then pick a random spot (above, below, left, right) and set that one to 1 as well. It works perfectly fine through the first loop, but then gives me an array out of bounds error after that.

```
public static void checkPopulation() {
    for(int x = 0; x < Canvas.length; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < Canvas.length; y++) {
            if(Canvas[x][y] != 0) {
                particleDiffusion(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void particleDiffusion(int x, int y) {
    Random r = new Random();
    if(r.nextInt(3) == 0) {
        Canvas[x+1][y] = 255;
    } else if(r.nextInt(3) == 1) {
        Canvas[x][y+1] = 255;
    } else if(r.nextInt(3) == 2) {
        Canvas[x-1][y] = 255;//THIS IS WHERE ERROR IS POINTING
    } else if(r.nextInt(3) == 3) {
        Canvas[x][y-1] = 255;
    }
    if(stepsTaken < diffusionStep) {
        checkPopulation();
    } else {
        System.out.println("done");
        return;
    }
}
```

can somebody help me with what I am doing wrong? And why it loops through once and then gives the error?

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger? What happens when `x = 0` at the line you indicated?

Comment: Are you sure that you get `square 2-d array`..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, let's walk through all your problems one by one.

1. The indices. This is obvious and I won't discuss it further.
2. `checkPopulation()` and `particleDiffusion()` recursively invoke each other. Since neither `stepsTaken` or `diffusionStep` are modified in the code path you will eventually see a StackOverflow. You don't seem to need to use recursion for this, why not use a loop instead? I'm assuming you have an initial call to `checkPopulation()`, so how about replacing it with:

   ```
   for (int stepsTaken = 0; stepsTaken < diffusionStep; stepsTaken++) {
       checkPopulation();
   }
   ```

   Right now, at a high level, your methods look like

   ```
   main() {
       checkPopulation();
   }

   checkPopulation() {
       ...
       particleDiffusion();
   }

   particleDiffusion() {
       ...
       if (stepsTaken < diffusionStep) {
           checkPopulation();
       }
   }
   ```

   With the change, it now looks like

   ```
   main() {
       for (int stepsTaken = 0; stepsTaken < diffusionStep; stepsTaken++) {
           checkPopulation();
       }
   }

   checkPopulation() {
       ...
       particleDiffusion();
   }

   particleDiffusion() {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Calling `r.nextInt(3) == x` multiple times does not distribute the probability across the four directions evenly. There's no guarantee any of the four cases will actually be successful. Save the result of `r.nextInt(3)` in a variable and then do the comparison on that variable.

Comment: Everytime particleDiffusion is called, stepsTaken++.

Comment: @Tyson Sure. If `diffusionStep` is large you'll still have a StackOverflow. Using a loop solves this completely and is clearer.

Comment: I put all of this inside of a loop that loops through diffusionStep? So completely eliminate particleDiffusion and loop through both at the same time?

Answer (score 5):

You check if x and y are less than Canvas.length, then you use x+1 and y+1 as array indexes, that's the reason. The fixed code is below.

```
public static void checkPopulation() {
    for(int x = 0; x < Canvas.length; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < Canvas.length; y++) {
            if(Canvas[x][y] != 0) {
                particleDiffusion(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void particleDiffusion(int x, int y) {
    Random r = new Random();
    if(r.nextInt(3) == 0) {
        if( x+1 < Canvas.length)
            Canvas[x+1][y] = 255;
    } else if(r.nextInt(3) == 1) {
        if( y+1 < Canvas.length)
            Canvas[x][y+1] = 255;
    } else if(r.nextInt(3) == 2) {
        if( x > 0)
            Canvas[x-1][y] = 255;//THIS IS WHERE ERROR IS POINTING
    } else if(r.nextInt(3) == 3) {
        if( y > 0)
            Canvas[x][y-1] = 255;
    }
    if(stepsTaken < diffusionStep) {
        checkPopulation();
    } else {
        System.out.println("done");
        return;
    }
}
```

Edit: Also you should check x-1 and y-1 are not negative.

Comment: I had already tried that, and it gives me a stackoverflow error.

Comment: @Tyson: Then that's a different problem... and probably one related to the fact that you don't appear to change `stepsTaken` or `diffusionStep` anywhere in the code... how do you *expect* it to stop recursing?

Comment: I do change it, every time checkPopulation gets called stepsTaken++ I just didn't paste that part.